# Extracting dimensions of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I've got this matrix Q:

```
            [,1]        [,2] [,3]       [,4]
[1,]  0.77325281  0.04054297  0.5  0.3878613
[2,]  0.01478692 -0.61477862  0.5 -0.6097775
[3,] -0.60774649 -0.19012961  0.5  0.5869369
[4,] -0.18029324  0.76436526  0.5 -0.3650207
```

I've tried to extract the first two columns of this matrix with:

```
Q[,c(1,2)]
```

Then I get this error:

```
Error in Q[, c(1, 2)] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Can anyone tell me why I get this error and how to get the first two columns?
How I computed Q:

```
test <- matrix(c(0, 4.05, 8.25, 5.57, 4.05, 0, 2.54, 2.69, 8.25, 2.54, 0, 2.11, 5.57, 2.69, 2.11, 0), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

# matrix of squared dissimilarities
test2 <- matrix(c(test^2), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)

# double centering and multiplied
n=4
I=diag(n)
J=matrix(1,n,n)
C=I-J/n 
B <- ((-.5)*C%*%test2%*%C)
B # double centered matrix

# eigenvalue decomposition
Q = eigen(B)
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Add the tag of that language in your question

Comment: In R, sorry I forgot

Comment: Rilja, your code should work. If it does not then there is something that is not being shown. Can you edit your question to show `dput(Q)` please.

Comment: I added how I computed Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit** since question update

If you look at the structure of the object that `eigen` returns you will see it is a list of length two

```
str(Q)
# List of 2
#  $ values : num [1:4] 3.57e+01 3.27 -1.95e-14 -5.57
#  $ vectors: num [1:4, 1:4] 0.7733 0.0148 -0.6077 -0.1803 0.0405 ...
```

You can extract the eigenvectors with `Q$vectors`

This is described in the help page of `?eigen`

So for your question use

```
Q$vectors[, 1:2]
#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,]  0.77325281  0.04054297
# [2,]  0.01478692 -0.61477862
# [3,] -0.60774649 -0.19012961
# [4,] -0.18029324  0.76436526
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I added how I computed Q to the question.

Comment: The edit was well suited, as his question had changed. If there is a way, I would upvote the edit.